# What does declare namespace mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

1. What does `declare namespace` mean in typescript?
2. What is the proper use case to use `declare namespace ~~~`?

Comment: Have you checked out the official TypeScript site about `namespace` and `declare namespace`?  They explain what namespace is pretty well here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Comment: No problem.  If it still doesn't make sense comment back and I can provide a more flushed out answer.